# private method `open' called for Chef::Provider::File:Class

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to create a resource that writes all attributes to a file.

provider [gist](https://gist.github.com/d58b6419f967a7ef7b48)

resource [gist](https://gist.github.com/ba1c498c84853e006eae)

### I'm getting the following error :

Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[dump_node_attributes]'`

```
NoMethodError

private method `open' called for Chef::Provider::File:Class

Cookbook Trace:

/Users/odedpriva/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-helper/providers/create.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in class_from_file'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your block, make that `::File.open`. Unfortunately this is required because of Ruby's implicit relative symbol lookups. The leading `::` forces it to be an aboslute symbol, like a leading `/` in a path.